# Android app to know the access point utilization

Tags: java, android, android-studio, wifimanager

I am working on an android application and I want to make this app be able to tell me how many devices are connected to the current access point I am attached to. What is the best possible solution for this. I don't want the details of devices instead I just need the number of devices connected to a particular access point. I want to use this data for my web GUI which will show the utilization trend for each access point. Please suggest the way how to do this.

Comment: I have asked this question again and again and I am not getting any reply whether it is possible to do or not.............Is there anyone who can provide an expert comment on this?

Comment: Hi, in order to get some response, I think you should add to your question your attempts. Try to post the solution you have so far. Also, look at this page on how to post a good question: how to post ggod question stackoverflow